# Unable to install applications (Oneiric)

Tags: 11.10, apt, aptitude

When I use the software center to install something, I get the error:

> **An unhandlable error occured**
>
> There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that
>   allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package
>   management related tasks

on using the command line:

```
$sudo apt-get install <something>
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

I am unable to install anything. How do we fix this?

Comment: Have you launched `sudo dpkg --configure -a` yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Implys that you need to try to run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: get `dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process`. I even tried `killall apt-get`.

Comment: Is anything else using `APT`?.. Synaptic, Software Center, Update Manager?

Comment: The program itself is called apt. You should look to see if you have it running anywhere else on the system as mentioned above.

Comment: @yayu , You should kill the `dpkg` process instead of `apt-get`

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong.. you have some broken packages or some dpkg didnt configure properly in your package manager.

do one thing ... open synaptic from terminal with

> $sudo synaptic

, then go to status and then broken packages. Right click on package that is broken. Click on Complete remove. Hope you will resolve it.

Or share your pu

> dpkg --configure -a